# preserve textbox data after an Ajax request with RenderResponse call with JSF 2.0

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, lifecycle

How can I preserve the textboxes values when I perform an ajax action with immediate = true? I need to render the entire form. I want to skip the validations and update model phases when the ajax action is performed. I've tried using FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().renderResponse() at the end of the method that is invoked by the ajax actions but it doesn't work. Old values appear in the textboxes or some data is cleared in some textboxes. I don't want to update the backing bean yet.

What I want to do is to keep the information that the user is filling in the textboxes. The Ajax button that I use adds dynamically more textboxes and I set render attribute, in the ajax button, to render the entire page (I need to do a complete render). Inside the method I call with the ajax action I have "FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().renderResponse();"

the button code is:

```
<h:commandButton id="btnAdd" value="Add" type="button">
<f:ajax event="click" execute="@form" render=":form" listener="#{ManagedBean.add()}"/>
</h:commandButton>
```

And the listener action is:

```
public void add() {
   Person p = new Person();
   ManagedBean.getPeople().add(p);
   FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().renderResponse();
}
```

I have an ui:repeat to iterate in the "people" List and the code of the textbox is:

```
<ui:repeat value="#{ManagedBean.people}" var="currentPerson" varStatus="i">
<h:inputText id="p" readonly="false" label="Person" value="#{currentPerson.name}"  >
</h:inputText>
</ui:repeat>
```

I was debbuging the JSF phases and I got:

```
[2/7/12 15:06:33:584 CST] 0000002f SystemOut     O START PHASE RESTORE_VIEW 1
[2/7/12 15:06:34:375 CST] 0000002f SystemOut     O END PHASE RESTORE_VIEW 1
[2/7/12 15:06:34:981 CST] 0000002f SystemOut     O START PHASE APPLY_REQUEST_VALUES 2
[2/7/12 15:06:35:553 CST] 0000002f SystemOut     O END PHASE APPLY_REQUEST_VALUES 2
[2/7/12 15:06:36:089 CST] 0000002f SystemOut     O START PHASE RENDER_RESPONSE 6
[2/7/12 15:06:44:364 CST] 0000002f SystemOut     O END PHASE RENDER_RESPONSE 6
```

It is there a way to pull the data from the textboxes and set it again to them in the view after the ajax call? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you could use a wrapper class for the persons in people. Then you can let JSF call the setters and the original person objects wont' be touched.

MAG,
Milo van der Zee